# Separate lock for each map key

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a map (entities) where the key is a string and the value is a struct. Building that struct is an expensive operation because it has to go to the database to load the data.

```
type entityStateManagers struct {
    entities map[string]*entityStateManager
    mainLock *sync.Mutex
    locks    map[string]*sync.Mutex
}
```

The function below returns that struct for the provided key. If the struct is not in memory it will load it from the database.

I didn't want to have only one lock for everything because that would completely block access to the map while **expensiveLoad(entityId)** is running.

I tried having a separate struct (locks) with one lock per map key. With that, only access to **entity_123** will have to wait for **expensiveLoad(entity_123)**, for example.

I still have to do more testing, but it seems to be working.

```
func (handler entityStateManagers) getStateManager(entityId string) (*entityStateManager, error) {
  handler.mainLock.Lock()
  if handler.locks[entityId] == nil {
      handler.locks[entityId] = &sync.Mutex{}
  }
  handler.mainLock.Unlock()

  handler.locks[entityId].Lock()
  defer handler.locks[entityId].Unlock()
  if handler.entities[entityId] == nil {
     handler.entities[entityId] = expensiveLoad(entityId)
  }
  return handler.entities[entityId], nil
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Is there something I am missing? Is there a better way for doing that?

Comment: This is a data race if getStateManager is called concurrently, because then handler.entities is written concurrently.

Comment: On second thought, handler.locks is accessed concurrently as well.

Answer (score 0):

i would say like this but i can be wrong, keeping two maps with same keys is useles, also pointers to mutexes are ehh.

```
type Wrapper struct {
    *entityStateManager
    sync.Mutex
}

type entityStateManagers struct {
    entities map[string]*Wrapper
    mainLock sync.Mutex
}

func (handler entityStateManagers) getStateManager(entityId string) (*entityStateManager, error) {
    handler.mainLock.Lock()

    val, ok := handler.entities[entityId]
    if !ok {
        val = &Wrapper{}
        handler.entities[entityId] = val
    }

    val.Lock()
    handler.mainLock.Unlock()
    
    val.entityStateManager = expensiveLoad(entityId)
    defer val.Unlock()
    return val.entityStateManager, nil
}
```